# When applying to Literary Agents do you attach the query letter or paste it into the body of the email?

Tags: agent, submitting-work, cover-letter

I'm applying to agents, most of whom want a query letter and most of which want applications via email. I'm confused by the format. Do they want the query letter attached or pasted into the email, and if they want it attached, then what the what do I put in the email? Arrgh. Help!

Answer (score 2):

**Read the instructions to the letter:**

The ones I've seen are extremely picky and each one will give you very specific instructions how they want things. There is no one right answer, and I think it's a sort of test to see if you follow their instructions to the letter. Websites like query tracker will have the details for this, or will link to the literary agent's website. Most do not accept attachments (assumedly because they would otherwise get sent viruses and the like).

Answer (score 0):

Every agent and publisher is different.  Read the instructions on their web site and do it exactly as they tell you they want it done.

In general most will ask for it to be put into the main email as  attachments are too risky and they refuse to open them for fear of scumware invading their PCs.